# Post: how to set created date after post has been published

Tags: posts, date, publish

For example:

- i click create post at Friday
- i edit post data i left this post opened and not published till Monday
- i publish this post at Monday

as published date i see Friday. But why? I want to see as published date Monday, not Friday.

What and where should i change?

I'm using WordPress version 4.2.10

Maybe there is some settings or some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use the **latest** version of WordPress.

As far as I understand this should have been **fixed**, for *drafts*, many years ago, see e.g. ticket [#8978](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8978)

I quickly tested this on a vanilla install version 4.6.1 and a *draft* seems to be *published* at the **current date-time**.

There are hooks that can be used to fix this, but make sure you don't have a plugin or theme that are causing this.

You can also edit the published date directly:

[image: edit published date]

Comment: There are hooks that can be used to fix this - can you show them?

Comment: I hesitated to add more info about that, since it's not clear why you get this behavior. But what I had int mind was e.g. the `wp_insert_post_data` filter that filters post data before it's inserted or the `edit_post`, `save_post` or `post_updated` actions that fires after it's been inserted. There are also the actions that fire when the post status changes, like `transition_post_status`. PS: You should consider having a dev install where you can e.g. try upgrading, removing all plugins etc.  @brabertaser19

Comment: yes... just that i need to `save_post` check only this action

Comment: maybe you saw somewhere ready solution? or code snippet?

Comment: I would rather focus on updating WordPress and find out if any plugins are causing this with a dev install ;-) Start e.g. with a vanilla install and check how it works there, then add the plugins, one by one and check. @brabertaser19

Comment: i've done it already... no... it appears again. So, i need to update on save_post the date

Comment: So you see this issue on a vanilla 4.6.1 install, without any plugins and default theme? @brabertaser19

Comment: yes, right you are

Comment: If you see this happening on the vanilla install of WordPress 4.6.1 you should consider filing a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) for this, explaining in detail how to replicate the issue. But for some reason I don't have this issue on my install, maybe I'm doing the process  differently somehow? @brabertaser19